# How do I check if a table exists in sqlite3 c++ API?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm opening a database file and potentially creating it if it doesn't exist.

But for some reason, this doesn't create the table.  Any ideas?

```
const char* sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blocks(id text primary_key,length numeric)";

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_, create_table_sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

I haven't got it in here by yes I'm checking the return code at each point.
There are no errors.

Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Variation on another given answer:

```
select count(type) from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='TABLE_NAME_TO_CHECK';
```

Will return 0 if table does not exist, 1 if it does.

Comment: For some reason this always returns 1 to me, whether the table is present or not, i type in exactly what is above apart from changing 'table_name_to_check' to my table name

Comment: @DanielPeedah If you do `select *` instead of `select count(type)` is there a difference whether the table exists or not?

Answer (score 6):

Execute the following SQL:

```
select 1 from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='TABLE_NAME_TO_CHECK'
```

If you get a row then the table exists. If the result set is empty then it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a right parenthesis in the SQL.  It should be:

```
const char* sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blocks(id text primary_key,length numeric);";
```

Comment: Sorry, the example above is slightly different to the actual to hide who I work for.  In the actual code the create table doesn't function still.